# Está dando erro quando eu tento fazer o ORM

Tags: orm, groovy, grails, gorm

Eu criei uma tabela mas quando eu executo a aplicação mais de uma vez dá esse problema. Por que isso acontece?

```
environments {
  development{
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/G2017;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
        username = "sa"
        password = "G2017"
        loggingSql = false
    }
}




Error |
2015-12-29 20:06:21,141 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR       hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table   MATERIAL_CONSULTA add MCO_ANE_in_id  bigint not null
Error |
2015-12-29 20:06:21,156 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR  hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Column names in each table must be unique. Column  name 'MCO_ANE_in_id' in table 'MATERIAL_CONSULTA' is specified more than once.
Error |
2015-12-29 20:06:21,177 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table MATERIAL_CONSULTA add constraint FK_3u9950vreiqdafld873700mg5 foreign key (MCO_ANE_in_id ) references ANEXO
Error |
2015-12-29 20:06:21,177 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR   hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - There is already an object named 'FK_3u9950vreiqdafld873700mg5' in the database.
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Grails? Poderia postar o seu DataSource.groovy?

Comment: 2.5.1 a versao do grails

Comment: Column  name 'MCO_ANE_in_id' in table 'MATERIAL_CONSULTA' is specified more than once.

Comment: Poderia postar o seu Datasource.groovy?

Comment: Essa aplicação tem muitas classes mas quando eu criei essa deu esse problema que nao sei resolver :(

Comment: O erro é bem claro: o GORM está tentando tentando criar o campo MCO_ANE_in_id na tabela MATERIAL_CONSULTA, mas o mesmo já existe. O mesmo acontece ao tentar criar a chave estrangeira. Enfim, o GORM não está indentificando que esses itens já existem no BD. Tentou criar um banco do zero pra ver se tudo funciona?

Comment: Já apaguei o banco e criei de novo e fiz tudo de novo mas dá o mesmo problema...O que faço??????????

Comment: Amigo? eu mudei o nome do campo e deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

O Grails (por meio do Hibernate) está tentando criar a coluna MCO_ANE_in_id, mas ela já existe no seu banco de dados. Por favor, poste o código da sua classe MaterialConsulta para verificarmos se não está mapeado duas vezes essa coluna no banco. Se esse for o caso, vai dar erro mesmo.